# How to SSR in Ionic/Nuxt application?

Tags: ionic-framework, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I am trying out ionic module (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/ionic) for hybrid app development in my Nuxt 3 project. And SSR turned out to be not working anymore after I installed `@nuxtjs/ionic` in the project.
So my question is "@nuxtjs/ionic doesn't support SSR?"  Thanks!

Pages should be rendered on server side. (API requests shouldn't be seen on network tab on Chrome inspector on initial loading of a page.).

Comment: ionic is for building mobile applications. Mobile applications do not support SSR